# "Medical reports indicate that the murder was committed with a sharp instruments."

Tags: tense

> Medical reports indicate that the murder was committed with a sharp instruments.

My question:

1. Is it possible to say the verb *indicated* in the past instead of the verb *indicate* in the present? And which is correct with this sentence, *indicate* or *indicated*?
2. Is the meaning of the sentence will becomes different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A medical report is generally a written document. Even if it was written some time ago, you can still read it now, and the report still indicates that the murder was committed with a sharp instrument: present tense is therefore the correct option.

You would use the past tense about a verbal report, for example that given by a witness at a trial:

> The pathologist presented  a medical report which indicated that that the murder was committed with a sharp instrument.

You would also use the past tense if new information were to contradict the conclusion of the medical report.

> Initial medical reports **indicated** that the murder was committed with a sharp instrument, but a video just received by the police shows that the victim was charged by a unicorn, and was impaled on its horn.

Note that **a sharp instruments** should be singular - **a sharp instrument**

Comment: Love the unicorn!